Django jwt cannot customize authentication return message
enter image description here[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/oTr8Qx1A.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/yrSsiK30.png)
Django jwt cannot customize authentication return message
`{
"refresh": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTcyMjY3NzE5NCwiaWF0IjoxNzIyNTkwNzk0LCJqdGkiOiI2ZDJmMGMzYzg2MTc0MDhkODExMGZmZmMxZDUxYjIxOCIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.lomSSwRHBLwzdfJgQUy4o-qxn9bb4_bF0ScNsRIDMWw",
"access": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNzIyNTkxMDk0LCJpYXQiOjE3MjI1OTA3OTQsImp0aSI6ImYwZmI2MjI5ZGQ1YjRlZDhhMWNmZGY5MGE5ZDRkZWViIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MX0.Va9l4cPqomfSeI3emtqjlczlho2fzkVvSerQ-_jWR0w"
}
`

 'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema'


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I understand that you want to add a value to the jwt token response.
Customize the TokenObtainpairView that returns refresh, access token in the simple-jwt package.
like this
views.py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

  
# Create your views here.

class CustomObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request)
        response.data["hello"] = "world"
        return response


